# NRWL + NestJS Trying to use Swagger plugin

Tags: swagger, nestjs, nrwl-nx

I am using NRWL, I used it to generate a Nestjs + angular app, however, I am missing the Nest-cli.json file where I am trying to add the line `"plugins": ["@nestjs/swagger/plugin"]` For the swagger properties. Does anyone know how to Add the nest-cli.json as required in this tutorial: https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is already an open [BUG #2147](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2147) for the same issue and there are multiple solutions presented in the long on going discussion but none of them are full proof and some have side effects. Nonetheless I would highly recommend you to read discussion and monitor it.

Comment: August 2021: looks like this was "fixed" in a PR from NRWL but I haven't found documentation on how to use it yet. PR link: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/6677

Answer (score 0):

NRWL doesn't use Nest CLI, however you can still achieve the same results by adding the Swagger Plugin to the webpack transformation pipeline that NX uses.

1. Open the `project.json` in the specific app where you want the
   NestJS Swagger Plugin to be active.
2. Locate the configuration for the `@nrwl/webpack:webpack` executor
3. Add `@nestjs/swagger/plugin` to the list of `transformers`.
4. (Optional) configure the plugin's settings like `introspectComments`

Below an example:

```json
{
    "name": "project-with-swagger-plugin",
    "targets": {
        "build": {
            "executor": "@nrwl/webpack:webpack",
            "options": {
                // other options 
                "transformers": [
                    // register plugins here
                    {
                        "name": "@nestjs/swagger/plugin",
                        "options": {
                            "introspectComments": true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: this does not work for the nx 16.4.2 and nest/swagger 7.1.0

Comment: @PhilipAllStar do you know the latest solution ?